# Image validation in cakephp not working properly

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I am trying to add image server side validation in cakephp but they are not working properly could anyone help me...i am new in cakephp...here is my view and model file code:-
I am using custom plugin name "Account"
Account.php

```
class Account extends AccountAppModel {
public $useTable = 'users';
public $name = "Account";
public $validate = array(
'name' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter your name!'
        ),
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message' => 'Name must be alphabetic or number!'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 3, 20),
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'Name must be between 5to20 character!'
        ),
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'Name already taken! please choose another-one!'
        )
    ),
    'email'=>array(
        'notEmpty'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Please enter Mail ID!'
        ),
        'email'=>array(
            'rule'=>'email',
            'message'=>'Please enter a valid mail id!'
        )
    ),
    'region'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
        'message'=>'Please enter Region!'
    ),
    'city'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
        'message'=>'Please enter City!'
    ),
    'password'=>array(
        'notEmpty'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'please enter password'
        ),
        'between'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('between', 5,20),
            'message'=>'password must be between 5 to 20 character'
        )
    ),
     'cpassword'=>array(
        'compare' => array(
            'rule'=>array('confirmPassword'),           
            'message' => 'Password do not match please try again!'
            )
    ), 
'photo'=>array(
        'mimeType'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('mimeType',"photo","photo"),
            'message'=>'Please enter a valid image!'
        ),
        'fileSize'=>array(
            'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
            'message'=>'Image is too big please try again!'
        ),
        'uploadError'=>array(
            'rule'=>'uploadError',
            'message'=>'File upload field!'
        )
    ),  
    'photo_id'=>array(
         'mimeType'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('mimeType','photo_id','photo_id'),
            'message'=>'Please enter a valid image!'
        ), 
        'fileSize'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('fileSize','<=','1MB'),
            'message'=>'Image is too big please try again!'
        ),
        'uploadError'=>array(
            'rule'=>'uploadError',
            'message'=>'File upload field!'
        )
    )  
);
function confirmPassword()
{
    return $this->data['Account']['password']==$this->data['Account']['cpassword'];
}
public function mimeType($field = null,$cfield = null){
    //pr($cfield) or die;
    if(isset($field[$cfield]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($field[$cfield]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $size =  @getimagesize($field[$cfield]["tmp_name"]);
        //pr($size) or die;
         $imgType = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg');
        if(in_array($size['mime'],$imgType)){
            $return = true;
        }
        else{
        $return = false;
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
}
```

and here is add.ctp file code:-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Account',array('type'=>"file")); ?>

<table width='800px' border='0' align='center'>
<tr>
    <td>Name :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label'=>false,'data-rule-required'=>true,'lettersonly'=>true,"required"=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>E-Mail :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('email',
                array('label'=>false,'required'=>false,'type'=>'text'));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Region :</td>

    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('region',
                array('type'=>'select',
                    'empty'=>'Select Region',
                    'options'=>$strlt,
                    'label'=>false,
                    'id'=>'name',
                    'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>City :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('city',
                array('type'=>'select',
                    'empty'=>'Select City',
                    'options'=>'',
                     'label'=>false,
                     'id'=>'slct',
                     'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false
                     )
                );
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('password',
                array('type'=>'password',
                'label'=>false,
                'data-rule-required'=>true,
                'id'=>'pass_id',
                'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Confirm Password :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('cpassword',
                array('type'=>'password',
                    'label'=>false,
                    'data-rule-required'=>true,
                    'equalTo'=>'pass_id','required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('address',
                array('label'=>false,
                      'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Zip-Code :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('zip',
                array('label'=>false,
                      'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>About Me :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->textarea('about_me',
                array('label'=>false,
                      'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Contact No :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('contact_no',
                array('label'=>false,
                     'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Upload Photo :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('photo',
                array('type'=>'file',
                     'label'=>false,
                     'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Photo ID :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('photo_id',
                array('type'=>'file',
                      'label'=>false,
                      'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Show Info :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('show_info',
                array('type'=>'checkbox',
                        'label'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Premium Member :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('membership',
                array('type'=>'checkbox',
                     'label'=>false,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unit / Company :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('user_type', array(
                        'type' => 'select', 
                        'options' => array('unit' => 'Unit', 'company' => 'Company'), 
                        'selected' => 'Unit',
                        'label'=>false,
                        'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false
                    ));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>Status :</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('status',
                array('type'=>'select',
                    'options'=>array('1'=>'Active',
                     '0'=>'Inactive'),
                     'label'=>false,
                     'data-rule-required'=>true,'required'=>false));
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('submit',
        array('type'=>'submit',
            'label'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-default','id'=>'sb'));
    ?>

    <?php
        echo $this->Html->link('Cancel',
        array('plugin'=>'account',
                'controller'=>'accounts',
                'action'=>'index'),
        array('class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                'div'=>false,
                'escape'=>false,
                'id'=>'sb'
                )
            );
    ?>
<td><tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Comment: No no problem with video or text file ..actually when i upload image then show rule message 'Please enter a valid image!' i don't know where is error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rule ,(Replace your image rule with this)

```
'photo_id'=>array(
     'mimeType'=>array(
     'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
        'message'=>'Please enter a valid image!'
    ),
```